# session variable increment/decrement, session variable tracking on updates in js function

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have my code as follows,

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['rcount']))
$_SESSION['rcount']=1;
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
            <?php $_SESSION['rcount']++; ?>

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "text";
            element1.name="text[]";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);



            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            element2.name = "txtbox[]";
            cell3.appendChild(element2);


        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var text = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];

                if(i==rowCount-1) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    <?php $_SESSION['rcount']--; ?>
                    i--;
                }


            }

        }

    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
    <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "POST">
    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR>

            <TD> <?php echo $_SESSION['rcount']; ?> </TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="chk"/> </TD>

            <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
 </form>
<?php echo 'status of rcont ='.$_SESSION['rcount']; ?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

In the above code I dynamically populate new rows and delete the last row. I have achieved these operations using the addrow and deleterow javascript functions. However i want to keep track of the php session variable rcount so that i can use this value later. at any instant the session variable must give the total number of rows irrespective of the number of row additions/deletions performed.

Need help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to actually change the session value you have to do ajax to hit the server and change it.

Comment: You cannot change the server side SESSION variable using client side JavaScript. You'll need to do an AJAX request to update the server side variables.

Comment: oh okay. Understood.

Comment: I want to slightly edit my question now that i understood. How can i just display this raw table in order to preview? I mean at the moment I am taking inputs from user. I want to convert the input taken into a preview table which just displays the data entered in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax, or image object, like this :

Replace in `<script>` tag :

```
<?php $_SESSION['rcount']++; ?>
```

By :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "?increment";
```

On the head file, before `$_SESSION['rcount']=1;` add this line :

```
if(isset($_GET['increment'])) {
    $_SESSION['rcount']++;
    die();
}
```

Comment: I want to slightly edit my question now that i understood. How can i just display this raw table in order to preview? I mean at the moment I am taking inputs from user. I want to convert the input taken into a preview table which just displays the data entered in the table.

Comment: Use ajax preview or send the form to make preview.